# wpautop on section

Tags: theme-development, wp-autop

I removed automatic formatting in my WP site by adding this to functions.php:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Now I need to add it back into one section only.  On page.php, I want to replace the_content with wpautop formatted content.

I replaced this:

```
<section class="post-content clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</section>
```

With this:

```
<section class="post-content clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">
    <?php
        $c = the_content();
        $format_c = wpautop( $c, false );
        echo ($format_c);
    ?>
</section>
```

Unfortunately it is not adding paragraph tags here.  Can anyone help me to add paragraph tags only at this location in my theme?  I do not want them in the page custom templates or any of the posts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
$c = get_the_content();
```

instead of:

```
$c = the_content();
```

since `the_content()` will *echo* the content instead of *returning* it.

Or try this

```
<section class="post-content clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">
    <?php  add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php  remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); ?>
</section>
```

Comment: First method worked!  I am wondering, do you recommend one or the other as better?  Thanks so much.

Comment: ok great, if you are using some other `the_content` filters you might consider the latter approach.